# os.path.getmtime returning values in future

Tags: python, windows, windows-10

I'm having a python issue where my Z: drive is giving me `os.path.mtime` values 17s in the future.

```
import os
_file = 'Z:/tmp/test.pickle'.format(tempfile.gettempdir())
if os.path.exists(_file):
    os.remove(_file)
open(_file, 'w').close()
assert os.path.exists(_file)
print os.path.getmtime(_file) - time.time()
```

These are the results:

```
17.1539208889
17.1542103291
17.1539366245
17.1548016071
17.154453516
17.154258728
17.1541128159
17.1547086239
17.1553008556
17.1544091702
```

Does anyone know what would cause that? It's fine if I write to my C: drive. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Normally python should evaluate from left to right. but to be sure try following:
And I assume you don't have a horribly slow file system.

Is the result the same if you do:
`t1 = os.path.getmtime(_file) ; t0 = time.time() ; print(t1 - t0)`

Answer (score 3):

What is Z?

Is it a network drive?
Is it a drive on another windows machine is it a NAS?

I had this problem occasionally with NFS drives and it really screwed up things like Makefiles.

Then perhaps the reason is just that the clocks of the remote system and yours are not completely synchronized.

If you can log into the system of your remote drive, then display the time on it and compare it with your system's time.

If your system and the Z drive's sytem allow, then try to synchronize with an NTP server so that you can avoid the skew and both times should be aligned rather closely.

Comment: yes, this was the case - i asked our systems team and they found that the Z drive's clock was out of sync, which was good to have caught

Comment: glad the problem is identified